# Is there a nice way to switch a file extension in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to switch the extension of a file.  For example:

`test_dir/test_file.jpg` to `.txt` should give `test_dir/test_file.txt`.

I also want the solution to work on a file with two extensions.

`test_dir/test_file.ext1.jpg` to `.txt` should should give `test_dir/test_file.ext1.txt`

Similarly, on a file with no extension it should just add the extension.

`test_dir/test_file` to `.txt` should give test_dir/test_file.txt

I feel like this should be simple, but I haven't found a simple solution.  Here is what I have right now.  I think it is really ugly, but it does seem to work.

```
def switch_ext(f, new_ext)
  File.join(File.dirname(f), File.basename(f, File.extname(f))) + new_ext
end
```

Do you have any more elegant ways to do this?  I've looked on the internet, but I'm guessing that I'm missing something obvious.  Are there any gotcha's to be aware of?  I prefer a solution that doesn't use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def switch_ext(filename, new_ext)
  filename.chomp( File.extname(filename)) + new_ext
end
```

I just found this answer to my own question here at the bottom of this long discussion.
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179524

I personally think it is the best one I've seen.  I definitely want to avoid a regular expression, because they are hard for me to remember and therefore error prone.

For dotfiles this function just adds the extension onto the file.  This behaviour seems sensible to me.

```
switch_ext('.vimrc', '.txt') # => ".vimrc.txt"
```

Please continue to post better answers if there are any, and post comments to let me know if you see any deficiencies in this answer.  I'll leave the question open for now.

Answer (score 3):

Your example method isn't that ugly.  Please do continue to use file naming semantic aware methods over string regexp.  You could try the [`Pathname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) stdlib which might make it a little cleaner:

```
require 'pathname'

def switch_ext(f, new_ext)
  p = Pathname.new f
  p.dirname + "#{ p.basename('.*') }#{ new_ext }"
end

>> puts %w{ test_dir/test_file.jpg test_dir/test_file.ext1.jpg testfile .vimrc }.
 | map{|f| switch_ext f, '.txt' }
test_dir/test_file.txt
test_dir/test_file.ext1.txt
testfile.txt
.vimrc.txt
```

Comment: Pathname looks interesting, I wasn't aware that there was a stdlib alternative to File.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions were invented for this sort of task.

```
def switch_ext f, new_ext
  f.sub(/((?<!\A)\.[^.]+)?\Z/, new_ext)
end

puts switch_ext 'test_dir/test_file.jpg', '.txt'
puts switch_ext 'test_dir/test_file.ext1.jpg', '.txt'
puts switch_ext 'testfile', '.txt'
puts switch_ext '.vimrc', '.txt'
```

Output:

```
test_dir/test_file.txt
test_dir/test_file.ext1.txt
testfile.txt
.vimrc.txt
```

Comment: This will do the wrong thing on no-extension dotfiles like `.vimrc` or `.screenrc`

Comment: Fixed, though I'd say that any sort of mass-renaming function needs to have some filtering to prevent exactly that sort dotfile mangling:  file_list.grep(/\.jpg\Z/i).each { |f| switch_ext(f) }

Comment: Really? I need to remember /((?<!\A)\.[^.]+)?\Z/ when I just want to switch the extension of a file?

Comment: No need to be snarky.  If you're not comfortable with regular expressions, there are lots of other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def switch_ext(f, new_ext)
  (n = f.rindex('.')) == 0 ?  nil : (f[0..n] + new_ext)
end
```

It will find the most right occurrence of `'.'` if it is not the first character.

Comment: @Catnapper I think this is not quite readable, and is a little expensive, I mean, too much operations for this task: rindex, slice, concatenation and the ternary operator.

Comment: @kira this takes much less than regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, or you can use things like the built-in filename manipulation tools in `File`:

```
%w[
  test_dir/test_file.jpg
  test_dir/test_file.ext1.jpg
  test_dir/test_file
].each do |fn|
  puts File.join(
    File.dirname(fn),
    File.basename(fn, File.extname(fn)) + '.txt'
  )
end
```

Which outputs:

```
test_dir/test_file.txt
test_dir/test_file.ext1.txt
test_dir/test_file.txt
```

I personally use the `File` methods. They're aware of different OS's needs for filename separators so porting to another OS is a no brainer. In your use-case it's not a big deal. Mix in path manipulations and it becomes more important.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion of path separators, but your solution is the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
def switch_ext(filename, ext)
    begin
        filename[/\.\w+$/] = ext
    rescue
        filename << ext
    end
    filename
end
```

Usage

```
>> switch_ext('test_dir/test_file.jpeg', '.txt')
=> "test_dir/test_file.txt"

>> switch_ext('test_dir/no_ext_file', '.txt')
=> "test_dir/no_ext_file.txt"
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def switch_ext f, new_ext
  "#{f.sub(/\.[^.]+\z/, "")}.#{new_ext}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 1.9.1 the easiest answer is [Pathname::sub_ext(replacement)](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Pathname/sub_ext) which strips off the extension and replaces it with the given replacement (which can be an empty string `''`):

```
Pathname.new('test_dir/test_file.jpg').sub_ext('.txt')
=> #<Pathname:test_dir/test_file.txt>

Pathname.new('test_dir/test_file.ext1.jpg').sub_ext('.txt')
=> #<Pathname:test_dir/test_file.ext1.txt>

Pathname.new('test_dir/test_file').sub_ext('.txt')
=> #<Pathname:test_dir/test_file.txt>

Pathname.new('test_dir/test_file.txt').sub_ext('')
=> #<Pathname:test_dir/test_file>
```

One thing to watch out for is that you need to have a leading `.` in the replacement:

```
Pathname.new('test_dir/test_file.jpg').sub_ext('txt')
=> #<Pathname:test_dir/test_filetxt>
```